# .click in Javascript not having any effect - should update two elements based on array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, click

I'm fairly new to javascript and trying to create a language-learning tool that plays clips from a music video and displays a translation. I'm using arrays to organize and access the links and translations. However, I must have left out something essential, because clicking on the phrase elements to display each video and translation has no effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/KireniaV/XaK7G/1/

I created the clips using Spliced and am displaying them via an iFrame (also tried embedding the video clips, but ran into the same problem either way).

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="phrase1">Ne dunun bamimyon byori doeji</li>
            <li id="phrase2">naui jibun dwidgolmog dalgwa byori tujiyo</li>
            <li id="phrase3">dubon dashin sengson gage tolji anha</li>
            <li id="phrase4">sorobge uldon naldul nanun wetorirane</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

<h3>Nangman Goyangi (Romantic Cat)</h3>


<h4>by Cherry Filter, lyrics and translation courtesy of DavichiLyrics</h4>

        <iframe id="player" title="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI" width="341" height="192" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="myframe">You can't see iFrames :(.</iframe>
        <p id="text">Select a phrase from the song (to either side) to view a video clip, transcription, and translation!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="phrase5">Ijen badaro tonalgoeyo (do jayurobge)</li>
            <li id="phrase6">gomiro gumulchyoso mulgogi jaburo</li>
            <li id="phrase7">Nanun nangman goyangi</li>
            <li id="phrase8">sulphun doshirul bichwo chumchunun jagun byolbid</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#889999;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#999988;
}
.nav {
    float: left;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 341px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var videos = [];
videos[1] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=26&end=31";
videos[2] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=31&end=37";
videos[3] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=38&end=42";
videos[4] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=43&end=49";
videos[5] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=49&end=54";
videos[6] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=55&end=60";
videos[7] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=60&end=65";
videos[8] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/U6EcOiKWfZI&start=65&end=72";


var translations = [];
translations[1] = "In the dark night, My eyes become stars.";
translations[2] = "I won’t rob a fish market again.";
translations[3] = "My weeping days and days, I’m quite alone.";
translations[4] = "Now, I will go to the sea.";
translations[5] = "To catch fish using spider’s web.";
translations[6] = "I’m a romantic cat.";
translations[7] = "I’m a tiny star twinkling over the lonely city.";
translations[8] = "My deep and sad sea, it has gone away.";

function changePhrase3(clicked) {
    var oldText = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
    var newText = translations[clicked];
    oldText = newText;
    document.getElementById('player').src = videos[clicked];
}

document.getElementById('phrase1').click(changePhrase(1));
document.getElementById('phrase2').click(changePhrase(2));
document.getElementById('phrase3').click(changePhrase(3));
document.getElementById('phrase4').click(changePhrase(4));
document.getElementById('phrase5').click(changePhrase(5));
document.getElementById('phrase6').click(changePhrase(6));
document.getElementById('phrase7').click(changePhrase(7));
document.getElementById('phrase8').click(changePhrase(8));
```

Comment: your function name is `changePhrase3` but you are trying to call `changePhrase` and to set `changePhrase3` to execute on click you just provide the name, as it is now you are executing it and trying to set the return as the event function. You should be getting errors in your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo and invalid call.

I just fixed it. please checkout <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/XaK7G/5/)</kbd>

First rename function `changePhrase3` to `changePhrase` (3 is typo).

Second you should bind click function likes this. (`#` is not needed, use `onclick` instead of `click`)

```
document.getElementById('phrase1').onclick = function(){ changePhrase(1) };
```

because if you bind like `document.getElementById('phrase1').click(changePhrase(1));` is means you send the `result of changePhrase(1)` to `click` function. so you have to warp it up in function.

Third modify `changePhrase` like this

```
function changePhrase(clicked){
    var newText = translations[clicked]; // get new text
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = newText; // assign to the old one
    document.getElementById('player').src = videos[clicked];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few little things awry here,

Firstly, as Patrick Evans pointed out in the comments, there is a typo in either your function name, or your function calls. Make sure these match up.

Secondly, `click()` is a jQuery method; You are using straight JS, so you want to use 'onclick':

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

And last of all, `getElementById` does not require the '#' symbol.. You've got this right in the code in your post, but not in the fiddle. Just double check that this is how it is in your actual code.

All in all, you should get something like this for your click event listeners:

`document.getElementById('phrase1').onclick=function(){changePhrase3(1)};`

Answer (score 0):

Added `autoplay=1` to your youtube links so they would play immediately.

Changed some of your jQuery functions `click()` to normal javascript `onclick`.

You don't care about what the old text was for your translation, just what the container is so you can update it, correct?  This should get you started:

```
var txtContainer = document.getElementById('text');
var newText = translations[clicked];
txtContainer.innerHTML = newText;
document.getElementById('player').src = videos[clicked];
```

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/XaK7G/3/

Gomiro gumulchyoso mulgogi jaburo.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try the autoplay feature you suggest--Not sure if it would slow the page down too much, but if not this is a great idea!

Comment: It shouldn't slow anything down. Just check out the jsfiddle link.  When you click on a lyric, it plays that part of the video and displays the translation. Good luck on your project.